# retrieve data from a column in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

As I know, the `SELECT` syntax is used for getting data from a row instead of column, here I have a column called time in a table, and I just want to select all the data in this time column, put them in an array, and use this array later.

So how can I select a column of data and put them into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query: SELECT time FROM Table

Use this query to populate an array in python!

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(user="yourUser",passwd="1337",db="awesomeDB")
cursor = db.cursor()
resultSet = "SELECT time FROM tableX"
cursor.execute(resultSet)
for row in cursor
#do something here, maybe add to an array if you want
arrayList.append(row)
```

Something like this?

Comment: me too. If it was helpful, please upvote and mark as answer as it gives incentive to users to answer questions :)